# Prolog: Counting occurrences of an element in a list returning multiple answers

Tags: prolog

I'm having a bit of trouble with something. I've wrote a function that returns the number of occurrences of an element in a list. Here is the code:

```
occurencesHelp(X,[],N,N).

occurencesHelp(X,[X|T],N,Y) :-
    N1 is N+1,
    occurencesHelp(X,T,N1,Y).

occurencesHelp(X,[H|T],N,Y) :-
    occurencesHelp(X,T,N,Y).

occurences(X,List,N) :-
    occurencesHelp(X,List,0,N).
```

This works fine, the first answer I get is:

```
N = 5 ?
```

but then there are multiple answers such as:

```
N = 4 ? ;
N = 4 ? ;
N = 3 ? ;
N = 4 ? ;
N = 3 ? ;
```

and so on. I've tried tracing through to see if I can see why this is the case but can't figure it out. I think using a cut would help me, but we have been specifically told not to use cut, so that isn't an option. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When I load your code in SWI-Prolog, I get the following warnings:

```
Warning: /home/isabelle/occ.pl:1:
    Singleton variables: [X]
Warning: /home/isabelle/occ.pl:7:
    Singleton variables: [H]
```

These warnings are *important*. Singleton variables are very often a sign that you have made a serious logical error. In your case, let's look at line 7. It's in this clause:

```
occurencesHelp(X,[H|T],N,Y) :-
    occurencesHelp(X,T,N,Y).
```

Prolog tells us that `H` is a singleton variable. This means that it only occurs once in this clause, and this means that *we forgot to put `H` in a relation with the other variables*.

The previous clause says (procedurally): "if the head of the list is `X`, increment the counter". Conversely, this clause should say: "if the head of the list is *not* `X`, keep the counter unchanged". But it does not say that about the head of the list: In fact, it doesn't say anything about `H` (hence the warning).

So what you need to add is a goal expressing the fact that `X` and `H` should be unequal. Two ways to express this are `X \= H` and `dif(X, H)`. In your case, the choice depends on what you have already learned in your course.

(The singleton warning for line 1 is benign in this case; you can just replace `X` by `_X` to tell Prolog that you explicitly want to ignore that variable.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, adding X \= H does indeed fix the issue. Just for clarity, why does this need to be explicitly specified? From what I understand if X = H then it would use the clause that increments the counter, and if X \= H then it would go the clause that keeps it unchanged. Why is there an instance of the clause that keeps the counter unchanged with X = H? Apologies if this is trivial, just trying to get my head wrapped around it. Thanks.

Comment: @Faz because the case `X = H` will match both cases if your second case doesn't explicitly enforce `X \= H`. Remember: Prolog seeks *all* possible solutions that match your rules.